# Why are the current-voltage characteristics of a bipolar transistor in MATLAB and LTspice different?

Tags: transistors, ltspice, matlab

I simulated the 2N5089 bipolar transistor in both programs. The output I-V curve is completely different, although both programs use the Ebers-Moll model.

Spice-model of the transistor:

```
.model 2N5089 NPN(Is=5.911f Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Vaf=62.37 Bf=1.434K Ne=1.421 Ise=5.911f Ikf=15.4m Xtb=1.5 Br=1.262 Nc=2 Isc=0 Ikr=0 Rc=1.61 Cjc=4.017p Mjc=.3174 Vjc=.75 Fc=.5 Cje=4.973p Mje=.4146 Vje=.75 Tr=4.671n Tf=822.3p Itf=.35 Vtf=4 Xtf=7 Rb=10 Vceo=25 Icrating=100m mfg=Fairchild)
```

LTspice:

[image]

[image]

MATLAB:

[image]

[image]

All Spice model data were copied into the MATLAB model.

Screenshot of the first tab:

[image]

Result: the collector current in MATLAB is 4 times stronger than in LTspice. Why?

Answer (score 1):

> ...although both programs use the Ebers-Moll model.

This is the assumption you are making which is causing your problem.

LTspice generally uses the Gummel-Poon model of the BJT.  If no Gummel-Poon specific model parameters are defined in the `.model` statement, then it drops down to using the Ebers-Moll model.  I don't know much about how MATLAB works with BJTs, but [this page says it uses Ebers-Moll](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/npnbipolartransistor.html) while [this page gives an option to use Gummel-Poon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ref/spicenpn.html).  Your screenshot looks like it's closer to the first link, and I would guess it's simply ignoring the additional Gummel-Poon parameters when it parses the `.model` statement.

The 7 parameters used to define an Ebers-Moll **static** BJT model in SPICE are the following:

1. `IS` - saturation current
2. `BF` - ideal maximum forward current gain
3. `BR` - ideal maximum reverse current gain
4. `RC` - collector resistance
5. `RE` - emitter resistance
6. `RB` - base resistance
7. `VAF` - forward Early voltage

If you take your LTspice `.model` statement and remove everything besides these 7, then you are left with the following which looks closer to your MATLAB plot.

[image]

If you need to do experiments which exercise the large-signal **dynamic** model of the BJT, then you'll need to also add these Ebers-Moll parameters back in (or don't remove them):

1. `CJE` - base-emitter zero-bias depletion capacitance
2. `CJC` - base-collector zero-bias depletion capacitance
3. `CJS` - substrate junction zero-bias capacitance
4. `VJE` - base-emitter built-in potential
5. `VJC` - base-collector built-in potential
6. `VJS` - substrate junction built-in potential
7. `TF` - ideal total forward transit time
8. `TR` - ideal total reverse transit time
9. `FC` - coefficient for forward bias depletion capacitance

Answer (score 0):

Both models - Gummel-Poon as well as Ebers-Moll - do reflect the physics of the BJT which, in fact, is voltage controlled (Shockleys equation): Ic=f(Vbe).

I do not know how your simulation programs (in particular Matlab) react upon an ideal current source at the base node. Such a configuration is not in full accordance with the physical reality.